# query hangs, but ok if I update statistics

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Got an issue where i have a complicated sql query that occasionally hangs and doesn't execute on MS SQL.  However, when i run update statistics on the tables involved in the query, the query executes normally.

Any idea or pointers on the cause?

Thanks!

Comment: Either [this issue](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/03/22/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/) or parameter sniffing.

Comment: many thanks Martin.  I'll look into those.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server creates an "execution plan" that uses the statistics info to determine an optimal order to filter the data/reduce access to the database tables.

This execution plan is stored in the database cache and is re-used as long as the database is online; the statistics are not rebuild and the query is not modified.

When you update the indexes, the statistics are updated as well.

As a result, the stored execution plan for your query is no longer optimal and as a result will not be used any more.

I expect SQL Server also closes unused locks and transactions for the table before rebuilding the index. That is an undocumented feature.